# Connect Tikz Nodes running around nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to connect two tikz nodes with a line which should not overlap the other nodes. It additionally should branch below the node and run into the top again. I also want to label the edge/line.

I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=14em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=.6cm,
  start chain=going below,]
     \node[punktchain, join] (intro) {Introduction};
     \node[punktchain, join] (initRun)      {InitialRun};
     \node[punktchain, join] (nthRun)      {nTh Run};
     \node[punktchain, join] (conc) {Conclusion};
  \path[line] (nthRun.north east) -- ++(1,0) |- node{Iteration} (nthRun.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This leads into the following result (left), what I want is on the right (red color not intended, just for clarification)

[image: Current status]
[image: Should status]

How can this be done using tikz?

Comment: Does the following work: Replace the `line` style with `redline/.style={draw,ultra thick, red,->,>=latex}` and replace the `path` with `\draw[redline] (nthRun.south) |- ++(0,-.3) -| ($(nthRun.east) +(5mm,0)$) node[right]{Iteration}|- ($(nthRun.20) +(0,.3)$) -- (nthRun.20) ;`  ?

Comment: @percusse: Thanks for the solution, it works well for my given example, but if you add more text, so the nTh Run node gets higher, your code does not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=.6cm,
  start chain=going below,]
     \node[punktchain, join] (intro) {Introduction};
     \node[punktchain, join] (initRun)      {InitialRun};
     \node[punktchain, join] (nthRun)      {nTh Run};
     \node[punktchain, join] (conc) {Conclusion};
  \path (nthRun) -- (conc) coordinate[pos=.5] (dep) ;
  \path (nthRun.north) -- (nthRun.north east) coordinate[pos=.25] (stop) ;
  \draw [red,thick,->] (dep) -| ([xshift=1cm] nthRun.east) node[right]{Iteration} |- ([yshift=10pt]stop) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: @@theomega it's possible to reduce the code but it's more readable like this.